# parsley display error message from ajax response

Tags: ajax, validation, parsley.js

I'm using parsley validation to check if the user email already exist in the database ,

`<input type="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp" }'  data-parsley-remote="check.php" name="Email" id="Email"/>`
and for the the ajax  check.php

```
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$sql="select * from user where email ='".$email."'";
$mail=User::find_by_sql($sql);

if($mail) {  echo("{\"error\": \"Username exists\" }");  else echo("{\"error\": \"Username available\" }");
```

I can not get the error or success message to display in the form .... please help ,,, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding data-parsley-remote-message in the form input 
and in the check.php I added "echo json_encode" to return true or false based on the condition